# In a low-latency application, Is unordered_map ever a better solution over vector?

Tags: c++, data-structures, low-latency

Is it advisable to use `unordered_map` in place of `vector` while developing a low-latency application ?

I recently appeared for an interview with a financial company which worked on low-latency trading applications. I was asked a question for which I answered using an `unordered_map` which seemed pretty good efficiency-wise (`0(n)`) compared to If I had used a vector (`O(n*n)`). However, I know that it is advisable to use vector as much as possible and avoid `unordered_map` in order to utilize benefits of cache coherence.  I just wanted to see If there is a better solution possible for this problem  The problem I was asked was to check If two strings are a permutation of each other.

```
bool isPermutation(const std::string& first, const std::string& second) {
    std::unordered_map<char, int> charDict;
    if(first.length() != second.length()) 
        return false;

    for(auto it: first) {
        charDict[it]++;
    }

    for(auto it: second) {
        if(charDict.count(it) > 0) {
        --charDict[it];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can assume that both strings are equal length and the function is only assumed to return true If there is an exact number of occurrences of each character in second string as there are in the first string.

Comment: This is what a [benchmarker](http://quick-bench.com/) is for.  Test both implementations on your suspected data set and see what you get.  The cache efficiency you gain from contiguous containers vs the algorithmic gain you get from using the "right" container are hard to judge.  The real world often doesn't mirror the theoretical one so testing is your friend.

Comment: the big-O notation is for asymtotic complexity. What people often forget is the "asymptotic", ie for small enough N the complexitiy tells you nothing about performance. I think the only correct answer is: measure!

Comment: For that problem, vector would be a much better solution. You only are expected to have 26 keys (assuming lower-case letters of Latin alphabet), and `unordered_map`  performance is likely to be pretty abysmal.

Comment: @NathanOliver That is a useful tool. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanOliver in this case it is not question that `vector` would outperform `unordered_map` on such a limited key space. I would argue that in low-latency applications `unordered_map` of `char` should be ill-advised.

Comment: Why do you think you will get better cache coherency with a vector? For all we know, unordered_map could be using vector or some other array-like data type for its underlying storage mechanism. In your particular case vector is going to win but probably not because of cache coherency.

Comment: @SergeyA How can a vector be better in this case ? You have mentioned vector and key at the same time so I don't understand how it could be used.

Comment: @n.m. The difference is with `vector` you are guaranteed memory contiguity and compactness. With `unordered_map` you are just hoping for it. At best you can check for a specific platform with a specific use case. But locality would still only be, at best, as good as `vector`.

Comment: What are the possible characters in the string? just lowercase or just printable characters?

Comment: @AlokGarg I am not going to give you solution, for several reasons. But I think, I gave you some food for thought.

Comment: @AlokGarg If your keys have contiguous values (generally true for characters of the alphabet, but not guaranteed on all platforms) then you can arithmetically determine indices from the characters. Just subtract the lowest ordered key from the character value and that's your index.

Comment: No, you are not thinking of the correct usage of vector. You need to use it as a hash table with an identity hash function (the index is the key).

Comment: @AlokGarg A good term to search for is "perfect hashing".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The standard guarantees you many things, but real life performance is not one of them. For that, you need to test.

Comment: Thanks @juanchopanza for the lead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OP has assumed that with vector the asymototic complexity will be worse that with unordered map. This assumption only holds when the key space is large. But suppose for a second it is large. Then you have no guarantees. You can only hope that vector wins despite worse complexity, because of this or that constant speed up factor versus unordered map, which may or may not be there.

Comment: @n.m. It seems you misunderstand my comment. I'm merely providing a point of view with regards to your question *"Why do you think you will get better cache coherency with a vector?"*  Answer : because it has tight memory layout requirements. `std::list` might have great locality sometimes. Who knows how it's allocator was written? But you can't generally count on it. Though you can count on `std::vector`'s layout. That's why someone could *think* `std::vector` has good cache coherency. Which is what you asked. I'm not saying it's *necessarily* better and I'm not arguing against your point.

Comment: btw, your logic is buggy. `isPermutation("ab", "a")` will return true

Comment: @balki no it shouldn’t . I am checking that both strings are equal length in the beginning .

Comment: oh.. yes. I missed that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You have some guarantees about std::vector, but there's no guarantee of *better* cache coherence. You can assume a reasonable implementation will provide *not worse* cache coherence (because it has tight memory layout requirements indeed), but this is rather different from "better".  There are other performance-impacting factors too, so *not worse* cache coherence guaraantee isn't worth much without testing.

Comment: Firstly I'd take a look at std::is_permutation. Then for a cache friendly container consider boost::flat_map. Lastly, if your strings are regular words or names then the average length will be quite low (a bit over 5 for English). This means that big-O complexity doesn't count for much. As already said, you need to measure the performance.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, but it really depends on the problem you are trying to solve.  If the domain of your key space is unknown, it would be difficult to come up with a generic solution that is faster than `unordered_map`.

In this case, the domain of your key space *is* known: it is limited to ASCII characters.  This is convenient because you can instantly convert from item (`char`) to vector index (`std::size_t`).  So you could just use the value of each character as an index into a `vector` rather than hashing it for every lookup.

But in general, **don't optimize prematurely.**  If `unordered_map` is the most natural solution, I would start there, then profile, and if you find that performance does not meet your requirements, look at reworking your solution.  (This isn't always the best advice; if you *know* you are working on a highly critical piece of code, there are certain design decisions you will want to take into consideration from the beginning.  Coming back and refactoring later may be much more difficult if you start with an incompatible design.)

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only 256 possible keys, you can use a stack-allocated array of 256 counts, which will be faster than a vector or an unordered_map.  if `first.size()+second.size() < 128`, then only initialize the counts to 0 for keys that actually occur.  Otherwise `memset` the whole array.